# How does Windows do its timed GUI animation?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, user-interface

When I use Spy++, I notice that mouse entering a button triggers a series of WM_TIMER .

How is Windows doing this? Is it requesting that the OS notify it or call a function pointer after X milliseconds, or does the widget register its own timer proc?

The reason I want to know this is because I'm building a game gui api in C++ and want to incorporate this sort of mechanism.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS Windows's GUI animation capability is very limited. You can say nothing if you had known real animation capable OS like Mac OS X.

Windows GUI is a composition of various child windows which has own event handler routine and drawing code. Very clumsy and performance inefficient of course, only provide easy access to ordinary developers.

In short, I want to say that MS Windows is the least recommendable reference for developing a game GUI framework. If I have a opportunity to develop new GUI framework, first thing I would  devise is a mechanism to separate input event handling and graphic drawing for consolidated screen drawing, like game programs do.

Have a look at this:
http://www.rawmaterialsoftware.com/juce.php

[image]
<sub>(source: [rawmaterialsoftware.com](http://www.rawmaterialsoftware.com/images/demoscreenshot1.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 6):

I believe that the button's window procedure is using the [`SetTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644906%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to register the window for notification via a `WM_TIMER` message.  You can use `SetTimer` either to call a specific function after time elapses, or to trigger a `WM_TIMER` message with the specified information.

Comment: Do you know if there's a 'proper' way to do this with ATL/WTL, or do you just have to code it all by hand?

Comment: @Mehrdad:  Back when this answer was written, you had to do it all yourself.  Newer versions of Windows now have an "Animation Manager" to help you build animations like pulsating buttons and transitions.

Answer (score 0):

Game API's normally do their timing in the actual message loop of the application as most games draw sprites directly on the surface of the window, rather than using individual child windows.

Self animating controls that are build as child windows can schedule WM_TIMER messages to themselves via SetTimer, normally to process short term states - in your case the Button has probably used the TrackMouseEvent API to be notified via WM_MOUSELEAVE when the mouse leaves the button.

To allow more advanced animations in form based applications, Microsoft has introduced the [Windows Animation Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371981%28VS.85%29.aspx).